# Auto height of div

Tags: css, height

Browser shows div only when I set exact height. But i want to create resizable div according it's contents. Tried height: auto and height:100%. It doesn't help.

My div looks like that. It's background div of sidebars and content.

```
.wrapper
    {
        width: 80%;
        height:200px;
        max-width: 1260px;
        min-width: 780px;
        margin: 0 auto;     
        background-image:url(core/design/img/transfff.png);
        -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
my html looks like that

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(core/design/img/bg.png);
    background-position:top left;
    background-size:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}


ul, ol, dl { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; 
a img { 
    border: none;
}

a:link {
    color:#414958;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
a:visited {
    color: #4E5869;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
    text-decoration: none;
}


.container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.wrapper
{
    width: 80%;
    height:200px;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-image:url(core/design/img/transfff.png);
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    overflow: visible
}

.header {
padding:20px;
}

.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;

    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;

    padding: 10px 0;
}

.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; 
}


ul.nav {
    list-style: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #666; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
ul.nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus {
    background: #6F7D94;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* ~~The footer ~~ */
.footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}


.fltrt {  
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
-->
</style><!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
.content { margin-right: -1px; } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
ul.nav a { zoom: 1; }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
</style>
<![endif]--></head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="core/design/img/logo.png" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="438px" height="95" id="Insert_logo" style=" display:block; margin:0 auto;" /></a> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar1">
</div>
  <div class="content">
    </div>
  <div class="sidebar2">
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by its content ? Background image ?

Comment: Could you please post the way you use your `div.wrapper`? Is it like `<div class="wrapper">content content</div>` or `<div class="wrapper"/>content content`?

Comment: updated the question. please recheck

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`div`'s will naturally resize in accordance with their content.

If you set no height on your div, it will expand to contain its conent.

An exception to this rule is when the div contains floating elements. If this is the case you'll need to do a bit extra to ensure that the containing div (wrapper) clears the floats.

Here's some ways to do this:

```
#wrapper{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or

```
#wrapper:after
{
content:".";
display:block;
clear:both;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

---

Comment: "If you set no height on your div, it will expand to contain its conent." Removed the height from css. The div behind the content totally disappeared

Comment: Post your HTML. You must be doing something a bit askew

Comment: Looking at your HTML, you have no content. Is the problem that the background image doesn't show when the height isn't set? Are you expecting the div to expand to the height of the background image, even when there's no content?

Answer (score 4):

make sure the content inside your div ended with clear:both style

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Latest solution of the problem:

In your CSS file write the following class called **.clearfix** along with the pseudo selector **:after**

```
.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
```

Then, in your HTML, add the **.clearfix** class to your parent Div. For example:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

It should work always. You can call the class name as *.group* instead of *.clearfix* , as it will make the code more semantic.
Note that, it is Not necessary to add the dot or even a space in the value of *Content* between the double quotation "".

Source: http://css-snippets.com/page/2/

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/200.htm), you need to assign a height to the element in which the div is contained in order for 100% height to work. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

As stated earlier by Jamie Dixon, a floated `<div>` is taken out of normal flow. All content that is still within normal flow will ignore it completely and not make space for it.

Try putting a different colored border `border:solid 1px orange;` around each of your `<div>` elements to see what they're doing. You might start by removing the floats and putting some dummy text inside the div. Then style them one at a time to get the desired layout.