# CSS - Automatic div height?

Tags: html, css

I have a main container where the whole site is based around.

Inside the container, other than all the headers, text & footers etc. I have some expandable div's which slide up and down, thus the need to have the overall height of the container to adjust to the size of the expanded divs.

Now, I have done this before just using: height:100%, but for some reason, that causes the border effects of the container to disappear. It only seems to work with a fixed height such as: height:1000px.

**CSS:**

```
   #container {
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        width: 980px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
        -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
    }
```

**HTML:** (pretty much like this)

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top-banner">
    <div id="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col1">text+expandable divs</div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: we're going to need to see the `html`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto height of div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857078/auto-height-of-div)

Comment: The `div` natural behaviour is always to auto-expand, unless you messed up with it.

Comment: Your `container` `height` is set to 100%. But you're aware that its parent need to have the `height` declared also, aren't you?

Comment: @MelanciaUK `div` default behaviour is to auto collapse (at least if we're talking about `height`).

Comment: Not a duplicate. @MelanciaUK failed to understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you are setting `height: 100%;` as `relative` then this means that `#container` should have height `100%` in relation to the parent of `container` id, which in this case should be `body`.

Set    `body,html{height:100%}` and this should work!

**Eg**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have to give

```
.container
{
  height: 100%; 
  position: relative
}
```

then

```
#wrapper
{
 height:100%;
}
```

is a must!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand it better now. The solution you gave works, but cuts of the bottom slightly. I guess it is likely to do with my footer, so I will add some margin/padding and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It disappears, because with the 100% value, your container's height is the same as that of your body tag. So you have to extend your body and your html tags like this:

```
html{
   height: 95%;
}
body{
   height: 95%;
} 
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 980px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159,159,159,0.6);
}
```

On some browsers, you have to add min-height:95%.

Here is the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/axv5j/

Comment: Thanks yochannah. Sorry, I'm not fluent in English

Answer (score 0):

Added a wrapper, and set HTML, body to 100% height:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
    height:100%;    
}
```

Then added:

```
    padding-bottom:150px;
```

to the container to increase the size enough to cover the content.